# why is it when i run this program after entering 10 numbers it gives me the first number occurs 100 times?

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Ex7_3 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("This program that reads the integers between 1 and 100 and counts the occurrences of each");
    int [] counts = new int [101];
    System.out.println("Enter the integers between 1 and 100:");
    int next = input.nextInt();
    while (next != 0){
        if(next >= 1 && next<= 100)
            counts [next]++;
        next = input.nextInt();

    for(int i =0; i< counts.length;i++)
        for(int j = 0; j <= 100; j++)
            if(counts[next] > 1){
                System.out.println(next + "occurs" + j + "times");

        }
    }
}
}
```

The solution should be like this?

Enter the integers between 1 and 100: 2 5 6 5 4 3 23 43 2 0
2 occurs 2 times
3 occurs 1 time
4 occurs 1 time
5 occurs 2 times
6 occurs 1 time
23 occurs 1 time
43 occurs 1 time

Comment: Have you tried adding println() lines to assist with the debugging of your homework?

Comment: You have a couple problems with the code.  You should be populating array first add all 10 numbers to the array.  Then after that loop (outside of it) you should have a loop that checks each number starting with the first index of the array and compares it with the other 9 spots in the array to see how many times it occurs in the array.  This could be done with an inner loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your loop at the end doesn't make much sense to me. You probably want something like this

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("This program that reads the integers between 1 and 100 and counts the occurrences of each");
int [] counts = new int [101];
System.out.println("Enter the integers between 1 and 100:");
int next = input.nextInt();
while (next != 0){
    if(next >= 1 && next<= 100)
        counts [next]++;
    next = input.nextInt();
}

// Here's the change
for (int i = 0; i < counts.length; i++) {
    if (counts[i] > 0) {
        System.out.println(i + " occurs " + counts[i] + " times.");
    }
}
```

Comment: I ran 2 5 6 5 4 3 23 43 2 0 it gives me 

2 occurs 1 times.
2 occurs 1 times.
5 occurs 1 times.
2 occurs 1 times.
5 occurs 1 times.
6 occurs 1 times.
2 occurs 1 times.
5 occurs 2 times.
6 occurs 1 times.
2 occurs 1 times.
4 occurs 1 times.
5 occurs 2 times.
6 occurs 1 times.
2 occurs 1 times.
3 occurs 1 times.
4 occurs 1 times.
5 occurs 2 times.
6 occurs 1 times.
2 occurs 1 times.
3 occurs 1 times.
4 occurs 1 times.
5 occurs 2 times.
6 occurs 1 times.
23 occurs 1 times.
2 occurs 1 times.
3 occurs 1 times.
4 occurs 1 times.
5 occurs 2 times.
6 occurs 1 times.
23 occurs 1 times.

Comment: I ran the same input you provided and got the correct output.